# Adding a custom field into the_content()

Tags: custom-field

Anyway to add a custom field into the_content() somehow?

I have the AddThis plugin on my site and it shows up at the bottom of my site right before my custom field, I would like my custom field to show up at the very end of the_content() and then have the AddThis stuff show up.

Anyway to do this?

Comment: how is the custom field added at the moment?

Comment: Like this, <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reviewGrade', true); ?> right after the_content()

Answer (score 5):

Try [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to append your field onto the content:

```
function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'reviewGrade', true ) ) {
        return $content . $meta;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter', 10 );
```

Use the [priority argument of `add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters) to control the order in which your function runs.