# How can I make my plugin display custom post meta data on the front end?

Tags: plugins, post-meta

I have been googling this for quite a while but have come up with nothing.  I am writing my own plugin and I need to display custom post meta fields on the front end on the archive page.  How can I do this from a plugin?  I would rather not do it from the theme files.

Comment: [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102421/adding-a-custom-field-into-the-content) might help.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Using the_content filter as @Milo suggests only allows you to add text. I'm trying to append post meta data with html tags and formating. Any clues about doing that?

Comment: @dg4220 You can add html tags with `the_content` filter.

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to get a code sample posted but, If if attach a string that includes html tags to the content using a the_content filter the tags get stripped when the and only the remianing text is displayed. Is there some other step?